# Azure DataSync with SQL Azure databases across subscriptions

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I am trying to synchronise databases in two different subscriptions using Azure datasync on the new portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync

On the portal, I do not get the ability to choose subscription or connection string to connect to a Azure database on a different subscription (this is not on premise)

The options presented are either
a) Database from existing subscription + database server
b) on-premise database- with a sync agent to be downloaded

Can linking to another database via connection string be implemented via API's or is there any restriction or feature limitation around this?

Comment: Double check your permissions for the other subscription. I'm still looking for the exact permissions you will need in the portal, but you clearly don't have enough. I just did small setup in my portal (I'm the admin for multiple subscriptions) and I can span subscriptions without any issues.

Comment: @virusstorm: thanks- my subscriptions are on different logins(for historic reasons that I cannot undo now)...is there a way I connect the two subscriptions to be able to access the databases across subscriptions?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, your issue is due to you having different logins for each subscription. In order to achieve what you want to do, you will need to cross add the various users to the subscriptions.

First, log into your Azure portal. Navigate to the subscription you are the admin for. Click on `Access control (IAM)` to manage the permissions for it.
[image: Subscriptions - Access control (IAM)]

Click the `Add` button which will bring up a dialog to add permissions. Simply select the role you wish to grant (I believe you will need contributor for this) and enter the email address of the user that you want to grant permissions to.
[image: Adding roles]